# convert Value into int from Object

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database

How would you convert an object into a int?

here is my code

```
 DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
                {
                    if (child.Key == "myAge")
                    {
                        MyAgeInput.value = int.Parse(child.Value);
                    }
}
```

here is my error
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Please provide the `child` object.

Comment: have you tried using `parseInt()`

Comment: Are you using C# or javascript? Please use the right tag.

Comment: javascript.. unity and firebase to be exact

Comment: But apparently your code is C# and you got a CS error.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the syntax is C#.

Try this:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
{
  if (string.Equals(child.Key, "myAge")
  {
    int parsedValue;
    int.TryParse(child.Value?.ToString(), out parsedValue);
    MyAgeInput.value = parsedValue;
  }
}
```

Advice in advance: Please, specify question tags and programming language rigth.